# Return objects with populated list properties from stored procedure

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm new to SQL Server stored procedures, so apologies if I'm being an idiot. I would like to use a stored procedure to return a list of objects, each of which has a property containing a list of related objects. For example

```
public class Question
{
    public int QuestionID { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}

public class Answer
{
    public int AnswerID { get; set;}
    public int QuestionID { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set;}
}
```

I would like to write a stored procedure that returns a list of Questions, each of which has its Answers property populated with the related Answer objects.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: Entity frameworks will do this for you, otherwise it will have to be a manual process

Comment: Any reason for using stored proc over entity framework or something?

Comment: @DGibbs yes. Only asking whether it's actually possible with a stored procedure

Comment: Its possible but implementation dependes on what do you plan tu use on client side? Entity framework, some other ORM, ADO.NET DataSet, DataReader....

Comment: Yes this will work, here are two approaches: 1. return 2 result sets (one with the questions, one with all the related answers) or 2. call a sprocs to get the questions then call a second sproc for each questions answers... - The first means you get the data more efficiently but requires a little processing, the second has more database hits

Comment: @dave_r It is possible. Post what you have and maybe we can help

Comment: @DGibbs ok sorry that was an assumption on my part that you did the down vote because of the tone of your comment, so my apologies for that. However, the only thing you have asked is if he expect someone to do all his work for him

Comment: @Ben Sorry but `Post what you have and maybe we can help` - above. A couple of class definitions doesn't quite cut it IMO. Done discussing this now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Actually a stored procedure delivers a *relational result* rather than objects. As an alternative, you could return XML using `FOR XML` and deserialize it into objects. Mapping this to objects is usually done using an O/R mapper.

You can use datasets and table adapters to get the relational data into your applications. Once loaded into the dataset, you can populate your `Question` and `Answer` objects.

Here is a sample toy code to fill the result of a stored procedure into a data set:

```
var ds = new DataSet();

using (var cn = new SqlConnection())
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("myStoredProcedure", cn))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
        adapter.TableMappings.Add("Table0", "Answers");
        adapter.TableMappings.Add("Table1", "Questions");

        adapter.Fill(ds);
    }
}
```

For actual development I'd suggest you to use a [**Typed Dataset**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esbykkzb.aspx) and a proper `SqlConnection`. However, as comments pointed out too, use EF or another O/R mapper if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your most basic type of ORM mapper.

Well, most basic, with some maintainability and readability in mind.

I would hit the database ONCE, but have multiple resultsets in your stored procedure.
And look into the IDataReader.NextResult

(as seen here [LINK](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311274) )

Below is some basic ORM.

```
[Serializable]
public partial class Answer
{
    public int AnswerKey { get; set; }                   
    public int ParentQuestionID { get; set; }
    public string AnswerText { get; set; }                   

    public Question ParentQuestion  { get; set; }    

}

internal static class AnswerDefaultLayout
{
    public static readonly int AnswerKey = 0;
    public static readonly int ParentQuestionID = 1;
    public static readonly int AnswerText = 2;

}

public class AnswerSerializer
{
    public ICollection<Answer> SerializeAnswers(IDataReader dataReader)
    {
        Answer item = new Answer();
        ICollection<Answer> returnCollection = new List<Answer>();

            int fc = dataReader.FieldCount;//just an FYI value

            int counter = 0;//just an fyi of the number of rows

            while (dataReader.Read())
            {

                if (!(dataReader.IsDBNull(AnswerDefaultLayout.AnswerKey)))
                {
                    item = new Answer() { AnswerKey = dataReader.GetInt32(AnswerDefaultLayout.AnswerKey) };

                    if (!(dataReader.IsDBNull(AnswerDefaultLayout.ParentQuestionID)))
                    {
                        item.ParentQuestionID = dataReader.GetInt32(AnswerDefaultLayout.ParentQuestionID);
                    }

                    if (!(dataReader.IsDBNull(AnswerDefaultLayout.AnswerText)))
                    {
                        item.AnswerText = dataReader.GetString(AnswerDefaultLayout.AnswerText);
                    }


                    returnCollection.Add(item);
                }

                counter++;
            }

            return returnCollection;

    }
    }


[Serializable]
public class Question
{
    public int QuestionID { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}

internal static class QuestionDefaultLayout
{
    public static readonly int QuestionID = 0;
    public static readonly int QuestionText = 1;
}


public class QuestionSerializer
{
    public ICollection<Question> SerializeQuestions(IDataReader dataReader)
    {
        Question item = new Question();
        ICollection<Question> returnCollection = new List<Answer>();


            int fc = dataReader.FieldCount;//just an FYI value

            int counter = 0;//just an fyi of the number of rows

            while (dataReader.Read())
            {

                if (!(dataReader.IsDBNull(QuestionDefaultLayout.QuestionID)))
                {
                    item = new Question() { QuestionID = dataReader.GetInt32(QuestionDefaultLayout.QuestionID) };

                    if (!(dataReader.IsDBNull(QuestionDefaultLayout.LAST_NAME)))
                    {
                        item.LastName = dataReader.GetString(QuestionDefaultLayout.LAST_NAME);
                    }



                    returnCollection.Add(item);
                }

                counter++;
            }

            return returnCollection;


    }
}






public class QuestionManager
{

    public ICollection<Question> GetAllQuestionsWithChildAnswers()
    {

    String myConnString  = "User ID=<username>;password=<strong password>;Initial Catalog=pubs;Data Source=myServer";
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnString);
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataReader myReader ;

    myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    myCommand.Connection = myConnection;
    myCommand.CommandText = "dbo.uspQuestionAndAnswersGetAll";
    int RecordCount=0; 

    try
    {
        myConnection.Open();
        myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

        ICollection<Question> questions = new QuestionSerializer().SerializeQuestions(myReader);

        myReader.NextResult();

        ICollection<Answer> answers = new AnswerSerializer().SerializeAnswers(myReader);

        questions = this.MergeQuestionObjectGraphs(questions, answers);

    catch(Exception ex) 
    {
       MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
    if (null != myReader)
    {
        myReader.Close();
    }
    if (null != myConnection)
    {
        myConnection.Close();
    }
    }
    }

        private ICollection<Question> MergeQuestionObjectGraphs(ICollection<Question> qtions, ICollection<Answer> aners)
        {
            if (null != qtions && null != aners)
            {
                foreach (Question qtn in qtions)
                {
                    IEnumerable<Answer> foundLinks = aners.Where(lnk => lnk.ParentQuestionId == qtn.QuestionId);
                    if (null != foundLinks)
                    {
                        foreach (Answer link in foundLinks)
                        {
                            link.ParentQuestion = qtn;
                        }

                        qtn.Answers = foundLinks.ToList();
                    }
                }
            }

            return qtions;
        }

}
```

TSQL

```
CREATE PROC dbo.uspQuestionAndAnswersGetAll
AS
    SELECT QuestionId, QuestionText FROM dbo.Question
    SELECT AnswerId, QuestionId, AnswerText FROM dbo.Answer
GO
```